# Machine learning algorithm that predicts text based output based on the input

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I have tried creating an algorithm that predicts outputs based on the inputs, like so:
input,output
a1,b2
b3,c4
d8,e9

As you can see these values increase by 1 each time.

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

# Load the data
df = pd.read_csv('hash.csv')

# Split the data into training and test sets
train_data = df.sample(frac=0.8, random_state=1)
test_data = df.drop(train_data.index)

# Vectorize the hashed passwords
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer='char')
train_X = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_data['input'])
test_X = vectorizer.transform(test_data['input'])

# Train a logistic regression model
model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(train_X, train_data['output'])

# Evaluate the model on the test set
score = model.score(test_X, test_data['output'])
print('Accuracy: {:.2f}%'.format(score * 100))
```

The CSV file contains 84 lines of examples but it has an accuracy of 0.00%

Does that mean that I need more examples or is there something wrong with the code?